# Can I make global registration pipe, guard for global access?

Tags: angular

Could someone explain me. Can I registration pipes, guards only in main module for access another module.
Example

I have main module, and user module. User module I register in main module. In user module I register user component where I using pipe. Can I registration this pipe only in main module, or I must registration in user module?

Comment: But I get error Template parse errors: The pipe 'localization' could not be found

Comment: Hold on I will make a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### To add a pipe in Angular2 you no longer have to implement it into your decorator.

- Make a separate file, which will hold your pipe's code, e.g.:

`anyPipe.pipe.ts`

It will look like:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'anyPipe'
})
export class anyPipe implements PipeTransform {
   //pipe logic
}
```

- Add it into your `app.module.ts` file:

  ```
  import { anyPipe } from './anyPipe.pipe';

  @NgModule({
     declarations: [ anyPipe ]
  })
  ```
- Now you have to import the pipe into your component's module file, e.g.:

**`user.module.ts`**

```
import { anyPipe } from '~pathToPipe~/anyPipe.pipe';

@NgModule({
       declarations: [ anyPipe ]
})
```

- Then just use it wherever you want in your component:

  ```
  <ul *ngFor="let elem of elems | anyPipe">
  ```

Comment: But you registration pipe in main and user module

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it has to be done this way. I just mistaken your question with decorators. But try it. It has to work.

Comment: It's not what need for me. How registration pipe, I know. But I want know. Can I using global registration for global pipes and etc

Comment: As far as I know, you can't declare global pipes, you have to import them in specific modules aswell.

Comment: Not working, you'll get the error : Type SubscriptionCurrencyPipe is part of the declarations of 2 modules: SubscriptionModule and AppModule! Please consider moving SubscriptionCurrencyPipe to a higher module that imports SubscriptionModule and AppModule.