# The @component in pipes not working angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I don't know about the component in pipes:

[] error

[error message ]
Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; pipes: any[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'pipes' does not exist in type 'Component'.

notice-list.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ocNotice} from './product';
import {NoticeFilterPipe} from './product-filter.pipe';
import {NoticeService} from './product.service'

@Component({
    selector : 'pm-products',
    templateUrl : './app/products/product-list.component.html',
    pipes: [ noticeFilter ]
})

export class ProductListComponent{
    pageTitle : string = 'Notice List';
    imgW : number = 30;
    imgH : number = 30;
    showImage : boolean = false;
    listFilter : string;
    notice : ocNotice[];

constructor(private _noticeService : NoticeService){

}
toggleImage() : void{
    this.showImage = !this.showImage;
}

ngOnInit() : void{
    console.log("Oninit");
    this.notice = this._noticeService.getProduct();
}
```

product-filter.pipe.ts

```
import {PipeTransform, Pipe} from '@angular/core';
import {ocNotice} from './product';

@Pipe({
    name : 'noticeFilter'
})

export class NoticeFilterPipe implements PipeTransform{
    transform(value : ocNotice[], args : string) : ocNotice[]{
        let filter : string = args[0] ? args[0].toLocaleLowerCase() : null;
       return filter ? value.filter((notice : ocNotice) => 
           notice.title.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filter) != -1) : value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are introducing the pipe in a wrong way. Read my answer and follow the instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42093552/can-i-make-global-registration-pipe-guard-for-global-access/42094880#42094880

Comment: First of all, you should declare the `pipe in your `module`. Now, if you pretend to use the `pipe` in your `.ts - component` file, you must change It: `pipes: [ noticeFilter ]` to: `providers: [ NoticeFilterPipe ]`. If you want to use it in *template* you just need to declare it in your `module`.

Comment: What is version of Angular 2 do you use? As I know, `pipe` no longer declare in `component` file; its must be declare in `declaration` of `module`.

Answer (score 2):

if you get this error:

Argument of type '{ selector: string; templateUrl: string; pipes: typeof MattDamon[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'pipes' does not exist in type 'Component'.

Instead of adding the pipe in pipes[] array in the @component,
add the pipe in the 'declarations' array inside 'app.modules.ts', and no need to use 'pipes' array

Comment: Doesn't this make the pipe globally available, rather than scoped to just the component that wants to take advantage of it? I can see your solution good when the filter is generic & needs to be available across the application, but my filter is only wanted in a particular component .. your approach doesn't feel right for that.